# string variable not able to get thevalue

Tags: c#, oop

i have an  variable  declated as an object
Object obj =e.Row.DataContext;

when i go to  immediate window and  check the value i get  like this

> ?Object obj =e.Row.DataContext;

```
{TempTypeMinus1487405295}
    People: "7,556,930"
    Name: "India"
```

**string strcounty =obj .Tostring();**

now in strcounty i should get as **India**

but i am getting the value  as  **TempTypeMinus1487405295**

how can i get  the value india  in string variable

thanks in advance

Comment: Fix up your formatting. It is very difficult to grok.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should cast incoming data type to your object

```
TypeOfObject obj = (TypeOfObject) e.Row.DataContext; 
or
TypeOfObject obj = e.Row.DataContext as TypeOfObject;
```

then your object has two properties as given info,if you wish to get **Name** property,you can access it within

```
obj.Name
```

If you dont cast it like this,you will receive name of type by default.

Hope this helps
Myra

Comment: what is the namespace used  for  to get TypeOfObject

Comment: !No,TypeOfObject refers to which type is bound to DataContext.It's just an example

Comment: hi myra,
 i am able  to get the value e.Row.DataContext;
 what does bound here means ? would you expalin me

Comment: Indeed,e.Row.DataContext returns you "object" type.I think you misunderstood me with type of object.Immediate window exactly shows you what name of object in curly brackets { ... }.You can also try obj.ToString() which will give you the exact same.I presume that,if your information is correct for name for object's type is 'TempTypeMinus1487405295'.Just replace that with TypeOfObject in my answer to see that it's working

Comment: i am able to get the value e.Row.DataContext. how can i assign it to any variable is  my Question if u can help me that would be great
 thanks

Comment: I don't know with the information you've given in the question.Explain more.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the object type that you have in the row, you can use:

```
TempTypeMinus1487405295 obj = (TempTypeMinus1487405295)e.Row.DataContext
```

Or you can use the new Dynamic Objects that Net 4.0 have.

Answer (score 0):

finally i solved the issue

in the datagrid event in  RowDetailsVisibilityChanged
 wrote this  code  and finally  for the value which i clciked.

```
var element = (TextBlock)dgCounty.Columns[0].GetCellContent(e.Row .DataContext );
string strcounty = element.Text.ToString();
```